# Why does ProGuard still warn despite -dontwarn and -keep class?

Tags: android, performance, proguard, android-proguard

I know there is an answer on another thread but I feel it is unrelated.

(Or it might be, but I'd appreciate a more elaborate answer)

So I have these in my proguard.rules:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.InstantAppsRuntime
-keep class com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.InstantAppsRuntime

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService
-keep class com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService
-dontwarn io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider
-keep class io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider
-dontwarn io.opencensus.impl.tags.TagsComponentImpl
-keep class io.opencensus.impl.tags.TagsComponentImpl
-dontwarn io.opencensus.impllite.tags.TagsComponentImplLite
-keep class io.opencensus.impllite.tags.TagsComponentImplLite
-dontwarn io.opencensus.impl.stats.StatsComponentImpl
-keep class io.opencensus.impl.stats.StatsComponentImpl
-dontwarn io.opencensus.impllite.stats.StatsComponentImplLite
-keep class io.opencensus.impllite.stats.StatsComponentImplLite
```

But when compiling the app, I still get these warnings for all of them:

```
W/ProGuard: The class 'io.opencensus.stats.Stats' is calling Class.forName to retrieve
    the class 'io.opencensus.impllite.stats.StatsComponentImplLite', but the latter could not be found.
    It may have been obfuscated or shrunk.
    You should consider preserving the class with its original name,
    with a setting like:
     
    -keep class io.opencensus.impllite.stats.StatsComponentImplLite
```

(that is an example)

Why is that happening? Is ProGuard actually keep the classes or did it not process by proguard.rules?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are missing the opencensus library dependency from your project.

Add below line to your gradle dependencies, e.g.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.opencensus:opencensus-api:0.18.0'
}
```